# zimbraAdmin monitor show server from previous installation

Tags: ubuntu, email-server, zimbra

If I open zimbraAdmin and go to **configure - servers** only the current server is shown.

But if I go to **monitor - server status** there is a server from a previous zimbra installation, and all services are with a green check (although with a stale date).

Am I running two zimbra servers at the same time ? I had a previous installation of zimbra with the second server but I have uninstalled it successfully running ./install -u and changed the server name.

Where does the monitor get information from?

Comment: Don't understand why this is getting a down-vote ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from zimbra forum:

> Please try the next article, maybe you have some old entry:
>
> https://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/ZmSetServerName#Clean_the_zmloggerhostmap

http://community.zimbra.com/collaboration/f/1886/t/1140119